# How to make a scrollbar in bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

How to create a scrollbar in bootstrap 4 dropdown selection. In my case if the files are too much then the dropdown will not fully loaded. So I plan to fix only 5 files to be displayed when the dropdown is clicked and have a scrollbar.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="pd-ltr-20 customscroll customscroll-10-p height-auto xs-pd-20-10">
    <div class="min-height-200px">
        <div class="mb-30">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Select ES Value</small>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <select class="font-14 selectpicker form-control" data-width="100%">
                                <option value="">- ES VALUE -</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using a Bootstrap Dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Give `<select>` tag a height and add overflow:auto to it.

Answer (score 0):

Give `<option>` tag to height and overflow.

```css
option{
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">- ES VALUE -</option>
  <option value="">- 1 -</option>
  <option value="">- 2 -</option>
  <option value="">- 3 -</option>
  <option value="">- 4 -</option>
  <option value="">- 5 -</option>
  <option value="">- 6 -</option>
  <option value="">- 7 -</option>
  <option value="">- 8 -</option>               
  <option value="">- 9 -</option>               
  <option value="">- 10 -</option>               
  <option value="">- 11 -</option> 
  <option value="">- 12 -</option>
  <option value="">- 13 -</option>
  <option value="">- 14 -</option>
  <option value="">- 15 -</option>
  <option value="">- 16 -</option>
  <option value="">- 17 -</option>
  <option value="">- 18 -</option>
  <option value="">- 19 -</option>
  <option value="">- 20 -</option>
  <option value="">- 21 -</option>
  <option value="">- 22 -</option>
  <option value="">- 23 -</option>
  <option value="">- 24 -</option>
  <option value="">- 25 -</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the **Bootstrap 4 Selectpicker** plugin. In that case the dropdown is auto-sized to the viewport height. To override, add a custom class to the select (mh), and then set the `max-height` using !important...

```
/* to set custom max height */
.mh .dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 100px;
}

<select class="selectpicker mh" data-live-search="true">
     <option data-tokens="">Custom max height using CSS</option>
     <option">More...</option>
     <option">More...</option>
     <option">More...</option>
     <option">More...</option>
</select>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/KfXbxL2OoF)

Comment: Yes I am using selectpicker plugin, However, your solution above is not working. Any other ideas? I have created `.mh` class in my CSS and added into HTML. I am not using data-tokens.

Answer (score 0):

In Boostrap 3 I've used this css:

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your list inside a DIV tag and set the DIV style overflow:auto and the DIV's height to a fixed height.

```
<select name='menu' class="myDropDown">
  <option value='1'>first item</option>
  <option value='2'>second item</option>
  <option value='3'>third item</option>
  <option value='4'>fourth item</option>
  <option value='5'>fifth item</option>
  <option>........
  <option>........
  //I have many options.....
</select>

<style>
.myDropDown
{
   height: 50px;
   overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```